# oracle open cursor

Tags: java, oracle10g

We are using the ORACLE A.S 10g and D.B 10g (10.0.1).  We maintain a pool of D.B connection on A.S.  Our application is web based. We are properly closing the resultset and statement on java side. But we often receive the error open cursor exceeded. Currently on production we set the limit to 5000. 
We use following query to check the currently open cursor

```
select a.sid, a.value, b.name, b.statistic#
from v$sesstat a, v$statname b
where a.statistic# = b.statistic#
and b.name = 'opened cursors current'
and a.sid = 555(any sid number)
```

The count of ‘open cursor’ is increasing it cannot be reduce until we restart our application server.
Because we are using the connection pooling that is why cursors are not closed?
Please guide us what should we do. What other areas we will look.

Comment: Are you also closing the connection? ( you only mention result set and statement )

Comment: he said they have a connection pool

Comment: But he didn't say that he closed the connections using connection.close(), which returns the connection back to the pool.

Comment: If your application is portable, I would try from another application server, so you'll know if problem is coming from code or from A.S. configuration.

Answer (score 0):

to find repeat offenders:

```
select c.SQL_TEXT, count(*) cnt  
  from v$open_cursor c
  group by c.SQL_TEXT
  order by cnt desc
```

Ref Cursors that are returned by stored procedures/functions need to be closed too.